# Java read from file and store only integers in two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have this method that reads only the numbers from a file and stores it into two different arraylists, one for each line. It stores the line as a string so it has only one index.

How can I read from the file and separate all the numbers so I get index 0-14 because I need them for calculation later?

The file contains this:

```
vot1:8,8,9,1,7,6,8,8,9,5,6,8,7,9,8 
vot2:7,8,8,8,9,4,7,8,10,7,8,9,8,8,9
```

My code is this:

```
public void readFileTest(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

        String line = null;
        int x=0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            x++;
            if (x<2){
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1); 
            numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
            }else{
            line = line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1); 
                numbers1.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
            }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    for (Object c : numbers) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (Object c : numbers1) {
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))`.

Comment: It gives me this: 889176889568798, it does not separate them

Comment: Can you post the code you tried??? `String.split()` function returns an array and not a concatenation.

Comment: Its because of the way you are printing it... `System.out.print(c);` prints each element one by one... So it looks like that... The array still has all the numbers individually...

Comment: Ok, nice. I will try my calculations now then